# yoast breadcrumb image separator

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm working with **Wordpress CMS** and I use **Yoast Breadcrumbs** (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumbs/ or http://yoast.com/wordpress/breadcrumbs/) to add a breadcrumb to the site but in my case I need to replace separator with image like the image below:

[image]

The image above is a breadcrumb output that I like to implement. And the default output of **Yoast Breadcrumbs** is like this `You are here: Home » Uncategorized » Hello world!` and the plugin has and admin option to edit the separator, but it is preventing HTML tag.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Do you have some example code of what you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoast breadcrumb is now succeeded by [WordPress SEO Plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) according to: http://yoast.com/wordpress/breadcrumbs/ you can customize the breadcrumb separator in the Wordpress SEO admin under `Internal Links`

Answer (score 12):

There is a far-more cleaner way to do this.

Read http://hookr.io/filters/wpseo_breadcrumb_separator/ , here they mention a hook. If u use this hook you can easily overwrite the seperator by just default HTML.

**For example:**

```
function filter_wpseo_breadcrumb_separator($this_options_breadcrumbs_sep) {
    return '<i class="fa fas fa-chevron-right"></i>';
};

// add the filter
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_separator', 'filter_wpseo_breadcrumb_separator', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old post, but I found this when searching for the same problem today. As of Yoast SEO Version 3.2.3, you CAN put HTML in the field for "Separator between breadcrumbs:" in Advanced settings for the plugin. I've used this code, for instance where I'm using Font Awesome but you could easily do the same thing for an image within your stylesheet:

```
<span class="divider"></span>
```

And my CSS:

```
p#breadcrumbs span.divider:before {
    content: '\f105';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

I hope this will help some =)

Answer (score 0):

In the settings for the separator you can add `<span class="sprite breadcrumb-seperator">»</span>`
This way you have a visible separator. But you can set a sprite based image on it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I already tried that sir but the field prevent HTML Code. The code output is like this `<img src=\"\" alt=\"fdgfdg\" />` or `<span>»</span>` and the field gave value like this `&lt;span&gt;&raquo;&lt;/span&gt;`

Comment: is the version uptodate? I use `<span class="sprite breadcrumb-seperator">»</span>` thsi one more then 1 site no tweaks involved

Comment: Ohh did see that, I assumed you where using SEO. good luck ;)